# Make bezier cuves follow/face/parallel to the mesh to make hair

Tags: mesh, hair, bezier-curves

*Why am I doing this:* I'm looking for an easy way of creating polygonal hair.

*What I'm doing:* As I understand, the quickest way is to convert the particle 'guide'-hairs to bezier curves and add a bevel object.

*The problem:* the curves won't rotate along Y-axis to follow the mesh - they're just lying flat (parallel to the grid). So when I add a bevel object, it looks fine on top, but weird on the sides.

Is there a way to fix that?

P.S: I'm very new to Blender, please excuse my noobishness

[image: L to R: hair converted to bezier curves | direction of curves (see the sides) | added a bevel object (a straight line)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by controlling the *Tilt* property on a per vertex basis.

It may be tedious will require some manual work if it is a lot of hair.

In edit mode just select a single vertex or a whole spline at once (you can do this easily from a single selected vertex by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and then controlling tilt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

You may optionally turn on *Proportional Edit* mode and set an adequate radius to control a bunch of hair at once.

[image: Curve Tilt]