# How to make stylized hair from curves with flat tips?

Tags: bezier-curves

I will be honest. I suck with curves and don't get how they work but for now i don't have motivation to learn it. Unfortunately it seems to be the easiest way to make stylized hair. I've seen this tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn7mISvVzJk ), the workflow looks super efficient, but my character hair are not pointy on the tips. I want them to be flat (or flat on one end and pointy at another) and still easy to edit as it was in tutorial. How to do that?
I tested few addons but in this case they weren't good (or I also suck at using them). I'm posting example of hair I have in mind:[image]

Comment: Just model the [taper object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn7mISvVzJk) accordingly, don't let it end sharp. Do I need to elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for a tip, but yes, I would like to see more detailed instruction. Could you tell me please not only what, but also how to do this? I would be very grateful.

Comment: "*I suck with curves and don't get how they work but for now i don't have motivation to learn it*" If you don't want to learn what do you expect to get from any potential answers? Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57360/would-this-spiky-hair-be-doable-using-particles-system/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/make-bezier-cuves-follow-face-parallel-to-the-mesh-to-make-hair

Comment: You can also download our awesome hair pack for blender here
https://blendermarket.com/products/ultimate-hair-pack

Answer (score 5):

> *I suck with curves and don't get how they work but for now i don't
>   have motivation to learn it.*

This will have to change in order to understand this answer.

1. Create three curve object. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Curve > Bezier

   - Taper
   - Bevel
   - HairCRV
2. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select *HairCRV* and go to the properties panel and to the data section. In the Geometry settings set the other curves as the Bevel and Taper object respectively.  [image: taper, bevel]
3. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the *taper* curve and go into edit mode <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>. Manipulating the curve will increase the depth of the tapered curve *hairCRV*.  [image]  This is, how a sharp ending can be achieved.
4. The Bevel curve influences the shape of the cross section along the curve.  [image]
5. Position the curve. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate, <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to change the tilt. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to scale.
   [image]
6. You can still change the taper or bevel curve. In the tutorial, there are multiple different bevel curve, to achieve a variety of shapes.
7. Don't forget to increase the resolution of the hairCRV in case of small detail along the taper curve.

Comment: Thnak you, you are great! Now I will be able to handle this