# How to make unique hairstyles with particle hairs/are there any other methods?

Tags: particles, hair

I was interested in princess peach's hair and wanted to know if I could make it with particles. However, styling it has been more than a hassle. 
[image]

This is her hair. It swoops around here and there and the front especially was hard to attempt, even separating the hair into different particle systems didn't make the process easier.

I was wondering on ways people style particle hair for characters that have unique hairstyles. I'm not sure if i'm correct on this one, but there was this sculpt which had hair which was first a sculpt, then a particle  hair that looked exactly like it! https://www.artstation.com/artwork/EO5lN  https://www.artstation.com/artwork/9VP9q

is it possible that they used a type of curve method to change the sculpt curves into particles, and is it possible to do it in blender? Are there any other methods I could use? Thank you, everyone!

*edit, I mean the stringy stringy type hair that particles have, the realistic type I think? Sorry for not specifying earlier. The type of hair in the second artstation link I mentioned.

Comment: If you are trying to achieve exactly the look in that image it doesn't look like it was made with particles at all. That looks like a simple mesh-hair made with geometry, maybe some sculpting. See this related [curve based approach](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57360/would-this-spiky-hair-be-doable-using-particles-system) and [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/make-bezier-cuves-follow-face-parallel-to-the-mesh-to-make-hair) too

Comment: I know it wasn't made with particles, but was curious on whether I could make the same look with particle hair. Is it possible, also thank you so much for your advice the the links! They look so cool! I'll look into them too, thank you :)