# How to flip normals/direction of curve geometry in 2.8

Tags: bezier-curves, normals

I'm trying to make a seat belt. I've pulled a loop off the seat and converted that geometry to a curve, and then extruded/beveled the geometry in the curve properties. It works, but it's making the belt vertical instead of laying horizontal how I want it.

I've searched around, some suggested using Switch Direction to change the way the normals(?) face on the curve, but that does nothing. I can't figure this out. How can I get the geometry on the curve to be in the horizontal direction?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59153/python-store-rotation-normal-in-bezier-curve-point/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/make-bezier-cuves-follow-face-parallel-to-the-mesh-to-make-hair/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control points on Bezier Curves have a *Tilt* property.

It can be accessed in edit mode

- through the Properties Panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) in the 3D Viewport under Transform: **Tilt**
- through the hotkey <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

The control points, which you want to tilt, have to be selected beforehand.

[image: Tilt Property]